# How to build graph or tree structure using online tools

Tags: graphs

I was looking for tools online where it helps me to create graphs or trees like below

[image: Tree]

[image]

What tools will help to create these? I am looking for both online tools and tools that I can install on my windows laptop and work locally.

Comment: At least the first should be pretty easy to achieve using [Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz), not sure about the second – or about "online tools" for this (I prefer keeping my data on my own computers).

Comment: Latex is certainly usable, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/613897/how-to-draw-trees-in-tikz) for example, but I guess it is not what you are looking for!